Getting GloVe embeddings using gensim, triu not found in scipy.linalg
I am trying to build a sentiment analysing model, using the GloVe word embeddings...
I found multiple sources on how to import the embeddings into python, this one seemed to be the simplest...
Trying to do the gensim imports, i ran into the problem that triu is no longer part of scipy.linalg (scipy version 1.13).
Going through other answers, i've tried to:

Downgrading to scipy version 1.12
to version 1.10 (for both of these the error statement still says that it can't find triu in scipy)
going into matutil.py file in site-packages/gensim and changing it such that triu imports from numpy rather than scipy. this time I got the error Compiled extensions are unavailable. If you've installed from a package, ask the package maintainer to include compiled extensions. If you're building Gensim from source yourself, install Cython and a C compiler, and then run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to retry
downgrading gensim to 3.4 and trying to do the same as above, i got the error: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)

While getting a solution to this problem will be helpful, I am also open to other ways I can just import the word embeddings into python... this was another method I found that I haven't tried yet, is this better if anyone else has tried something similar?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

At least post the command you used to downgrade scipy and the output - doing this worked find for me (installing flair which imports gensim)

for downgrading, I just pip uninstalled and installed the right version, confirming the version using pip list.

If you saw the exact same error after trying to downgrade to scipy<1.13.0 (such as scipy==1.12), then it's likely that either your downgrade didn't take effect, or only took effect in some Python environment other than the one in which you're still getting the error.
Are you using Python virtual environments to isolate your package setups per project, from each other and from the system's Python? If not, that's a good idea, and then being very intentional and explicit about which environment you're changing, and using for a particular project, may clear things up.
But most importantly: downgrading scipy should be sufficient to resolve this until a Gensim release with a fix is available, so you should focus on that workaround rather than other more finicky edits or rollbacks.
If you're still having problems, be specific (in comments or via edited additions to your question if there are long quotes of code/error) about how you tried to change the relevant scipy install, how you're invoking Python and importing Gensim to get what current error, and how you've confirmed that your scipy installation is strictly before 1.13.0.

I was using jupyter notebook, no virtual environment, for downgrading my packages I just pip uninstalled the packages and installed them again with the version in mind... can confirm this through pip list.
Still not sure how to get it to work, but the second link in my question had a method to load the embeddings just using a python dictionary, the function to do so:
def load_glove_model(glove_file):

    f = open(glove_file + ".txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    model = {}
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.split()
        word = split_line[0]
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in split_line[1:]])
        model[word] = embedding
    return model     # py dict

(NOTE: using gensim is still probably faster)

Manually uninstalling the latest Scipy version and installing the required scipy version (1.10.1) did the trick for me. Had run into the same issue earlier this week.
